# Getting Started with Xero-Python SDK…nightmare

Tags: xero-api

I’m a newbie to using SDKs, using Jupiter Notebooks to play around.

I have pip installed xero-python per Xero’s github page below:

https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-python

I saved the repository to my hard drive and opened a Jupiter Notebook within repository master folder and copied the code from the configuration section but get an error “no module called logging.settings found” (referring to the parameter passed into dictConfig)

Could someone help me get this up and running, I’m sure there will be a cascade of other errors after sorting this one.

Also, I’d be really grateful if someone could point me to some resources on how to work with SDKs, I’m used to just pip installing a library and just getting familiar with the objects/methods in that library.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Check out this library: https://github.com/freakboy3742/pyxero

Comment: Thank Karol, will take a look. Any thoughts on why  would get a module not found error on the official SDK? I noticed the Starter Oauth App project on the github page has the file logging.settings.py